# Postgresql custom c aggregate function throw a segmentation fault

Tags: c, postgresql

I am trying to create an aggregate function which returns the value of a column in the row which has the least/greatest timestamp. Below is the code which throws a segmentation fault for some large input.

```
    PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(minmax);

    Datum minmax(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
        if(PG_ARGISNULL(1) || PG_ARGISNULL(2) || PG_ARGISNULL(3)) {
            if(PG_ARGISNULL(0)) {
                PG_RETURN_NULL();
            }
            else {
                PG_RETURN_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(PG_GETARG_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(0));
            }
        }

        Timestamp epoch = PG_GETARG_TIMESTAMP(1);
        Datum col = PG_GETARG_DATUM(2);
        Oid element_type = get_fn_expr_argtype(fcinfo->flinfo, 2);
        bool is_min = PG_GETARG_BOOL(3);

        Timestamp minmax_epoch = is_min ? LONG_MAX : LONG_MIN;
        Datum minmax_col;
        if(PG_ARGISNULL(0)) {
            // first call
            minmax_epoch = epoch;
            minmax_col = col;
        }
        else {
            // state
            HeapTupleHeader hth_state = PG_GETARG_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(0);

            bool isnull_state_minmax_timestamp;
            Datum d_state_minmax_timestamp = GetAttributeByNum(hth_state, (AttrNumber) 1, &isnull_state_minmax_timestamp);

            minmax_epoch = DatumGetInt64(d_state_minmax_timestamp);
            if((is_min && epoch < minmax_epoch) || (!is_min && epoch > minmax_epoch)) {
                minmax_epoch = epoch;
                minmax_col = col;
            }
            else {
                PG_RETURN_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(hth_state);
            }
        }
        // return state
        TupleDesc   tupdesc;
        Datum       values[2];
        bool        nulls[2];
        MemSet(values, 0, sizeof(values));
        MemSet(nulls, 0, sizeof(nulls));

        tupdesc = CreateTemplateTupleDesc(2, false);
        TupleDescInitEntry(tupdesc, (AttrNumber) 1, "minmax_timestamp", INT8OID, -1, 0);
        TupleDescInitEntry(tupdesc, (AttrNumber) 2, "minmax_col", element_type, -1, 0);

        tupdesc = BlessTupleDesc(tupdesc);
        values[0] = Int64GetDatum(minmax_epoch);
        values[1] = minmax_col;

        HeapTuple rettuple = heap_form_tuple(tupdesc, values, nulls);
        PG_RETURN_DATUM(HeapTupleGetDatum(rettuple));
    }

    PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(get_minmax);

    Datum get_minmax(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
        if(PG_ARGISNULL(0)) {
            PG_RETURN_NULL();
        }
        else {
            // state
            //error here
            HeapTupleHeader hth_state = PG_GETARG_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(0);

            bool isnull_state_minmax_col;
            Datum d_state_minmax_col = GetAttributeByNum(hth_state, (AttrNumber) 2, &isnull_state_minmax_col);

            PG_RETURN_DATUM(d_state_minmax_col);
        }
    }
```

The seg fault seems to be in the function get_minmax getting the PG_GETARG_HEAPTUPLEHEADER argument. May be I am not building it properly in minmax function.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/pcf). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/guide/coding/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: This issue can be related to function registration - and transition type registration. For this purpose the tuple is slow - better to use own internal type - internally C structure with two timestamps - timestamps is fixed data type in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the above code. I was using the aggregate function in greenplum and not postgresql. For those writing aggregate functions in greenplum and implementing PREFUNC, make sure to check if both the arguments are NULL and handle accordingly.

Experts do suggest if any improvements can be made to the above function in terms of memory usage, etc